# Can I use a generic enum type as a parameter of a function?

Tags: c++, enums, parameters

I want to pass a parameter to a function, which is a enum. But I have many different enums created so I want that function to be useful for all of them. Is it possible? What I want to do is something like this:

```
enum Enum a {one, two};
enum Enum b {red, white};

void useEnum (enum anyEnum){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: anything is possible, but as always it depends on the details. What is `//do something` ?

Comment: Make a generic function, what's the problem here?

Comment: Have you heard about our lord and savoir: Templates?

Comment: In your example, the values for `one` and `red` may be identical -- how than shall your function deal with that?

Comment: ... Or you could use `int` or any other integer type, which can hold all the values of all the enums (best would be `std::common_type<std::underlying_type<a>, std::underlying_type<b>>`, but `int` is sufficient in most cases)

Answer (score 3):

You can make the function accept any type you like by making it a template:

```
enum Enum a {one, two};
enum Enum b {red, white};

template <typename EnumType>
void useEnum (EnumType anyEnum){
    //do something
}
```

However, I strongly doubt that it is a good idea to write one function that deals with numbers and colors. Without knowing any more context I would rather go for overloads or even more explicit:

```
void useNumber(a number){}
void useColor(b color){}
```

PS: If you stay with one function for different enums, then be aware that you basically go a step backwards. The main purpose of enums is to have type safe enumerations (`enum class` adds more typesafety), while inside your `useEnum` the only thing that the two enums have in common is that they have elements with underlying values `0` and `1` and thats what you will be working on. At that point using the enums has no more advantage compared to using raw `0` and `1`.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. The names were just examples.

Comment: @verlsk dont miss the just added PS, and if you like you may accept the answer of course ;)